# Android app chokes on per-site meta profiles

Tags: bug, android-app, per-site-meta

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a per-site meta.
2. Find any post.
3. Touch the user that posted it.
4. See something like this (click to enlarge):

   > [image]

As you can see, it says "Stack Overflow" as the site, and shows my SO rep and badges, but it shows my Meta.Code Golf posts.

Comment: Still repro'd on SE app v1.0.82 (beta).

Comment: @alexolut Is this still an issue?

Comment: @gparyani yep. I recently reported a [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304573/339911).