# Open user profile from meta sites shows wrong title

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

If you open a user profile from any post on meta sites (not MSE) via Android app, the title, site icon, about section and badges will be from the user's most popular site, but the list of the post from this meta site.

E.g. if you open my profile from any of [my MSO posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3240681) (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125/3240681) can be opened via app) you will see the following:

> [image: android profile]

Here are title, rep and badges from the Stack Overflow in Russian, but list of the posts and about section are from the Meta Stack Overflow (in English).

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)